# React Native | import file performance

Tags: javascript, react-native, import, export

There are multiple ways to import a file for React native.

1. Direct import.
2. First to export and then import.

```
//1
import BackButton from '../components/BackButton'

//2
import {BackButton} from '../components'

//components -> index.js
import BackButton from '../BackButton'

export {
BackButton
}
```

I was wondering is there any difference in performance between these two? Is it a factor that affects the rendering time, even if only a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the component from another file like

```
import BackButton from '../components/BackButton'
```

or you could also use component indexing for better import like "components/index.js"

```
import BackButton from "./BackButton";
import Loader from "./Loader";
import Text from "./Text";

export {
  Loader,
  ButtonView,
  Text
};
```

Usage like

```
import {BackButton} from '../components'
```

> It does not affect the performance but component indexing is a better approach to implement when you have multiple files in the component